# (beginner) Cannot access variable from void

Tags: java, variables, void

I'm creating a bank account program to learn OOP. I made a void method called `w_or_d` (stands for withdrawal or deposit), but variables made inside my void are not carrying over to outside the void.

It shows my variable (`finalbalance`) as `0`.

```
public class users {
  int balance;
  int finalbalance;

  public void w_or_d(int word, int amount) {

    if (word ==0) {
      int finalbalance = balance-amount;
    }
    else if (word == 1) {
      int finalbalance = balance+amount;
    } 

  }

  System.out.println(finalbalance);
}
```

Comment: I would *highly* recommend starting with a beginner's book on programming Java, or the tutorials provided by Oracle.

Comment: you need to understand the concepts of local scope and global scope

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are shadowing your instance variables with duplicate method local variable definition:

```
    int finalbalance = balance-amount;
```

just do the assignment instead of re-decalaration

```
    finalbalance = balance-amount;
```

Also using keyword `this` will make sure that you are setting the instance variable and not the local variable in case you have two such variables with the same name. So this is much safer:

```
   this.finalbalance = balance-amount;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int finalbalance = balance+amount;
int finalbalance = balance+amount;
```

these sentences override the

```
int finalbalance;
```

so when you

```
System.out.println(finalbalance);
```

finalbalance has no correct value.

just remove "int"

**int** finalbalance = balance+amount;

**int** finalbalance = balance+amount;

Answer (score 1):

You have declared `finalbalance` both as a class property AND a local variable inside your (poorly named) method `w_or_d()`.

You are altering the local one; changes to which are ignored when the local variable goes out of scope.

There are tutorials here: [Lesson: Classes and Objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html)

Comment: So how do I get the value of "finalbalance" outside my void?

Comment: @user313300 take out the `int` in the method. You're declaring it twice

Answer (score 0):

or can be used after `else if` statement as fallow

```
this.finalbalance =finalbalance;
```

so it assign finalbalance back to the class variable.